# mediaRecorder in fragment, prepare() fails, invalid state 4

Tags: android, android-fragments, mediarecorder

My media recorder stops in my prepare() line. Log cat says "invalid state 4" for the start() line which means that there seems to be a problem with my output file. I implemented my output file with

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/lastConversateRecord.3gp";
```

My Expression-Watchguard shows me "/mnt/sdcard/lastConversateRecord.3gp" for mFileName which sounds ok for me.

My audiorecorder worked in a regular activity but strikes since I changed to fragments.

I gave the Record_Audio + WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest.

Here is my code - have you got an hint for me? Thank you!

```
public class Fragment_2 extends SherlockFragment{

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private String mFileName;
private String TAG = "App";


  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);


     Button r1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.record);  


        r1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            //mFileName = getActivity().getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gp";

            mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/lastConversateRecord.3gp";

            Log.d(TAG, "Record started");
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
            }

            mRecorder.start();
    }

    });

    return view;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to give my emulator space on the sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the application does not request the permissions

Use in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
```

In your activity

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
```

And

```
public static final int REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE=1;
```

And later

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] 
    grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                    boolean permissionToRecord = grantResults[0] == 
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean permissionToStore = grantResults[1] ==  
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (permissionToRecord && permissionToStore) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Permission 
                            Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                }
               break;
       }
    }
```

I hope that it have useful :)